# Why does TinyMCE deletes my custom mpdf html tags?

Tags: symfony, vue.js, tinymce, mpdf

I have a vue app with symfony backend. I use tinyMCE to edit documents which are generated by mpdf. In mpdf twig content I want to add page footer on some pages, and somepages without footer so I creeated html tag to enable or disable this footer. My HTML of this custom tags looks like this:

```
    <pagefooter
            name="NotLastPageFooter"
            content-left=""
            content-center="{PAGENO}/{nbpg}"
            content-right=""
            footer-style="font-size:10px">

    </pagefooter>

    <pagefooter
            name="lastPageFooter"
            content-left=""
            content-center="{PAGENO}/{nbpg}"
            content-right=""
            footer-style="font-size:10px">

    </pagefooter>

    <setpagefooter
            name="lastPageFooter"
            value="off"
    />

    <setpagefooter
            name="NotLastPageFooter"
            value="on"
    />
```

Whenever I edit generated document via TinyMCE it deletes my html blocks provided by mpdf and edited documents have no page footer. Below my tinyMCE config:

```
<editor
    @onKeyUp="onDocumentUpdate(document, index, $event)"
    :value="editor"
    entity_encoding="raw"
    output-format="html"
    :init="{
        allow_conditional_comments: false,
        allow_unsafe_link_target: true,
        convert_fonts_to_spans : false,
        keep_styles: true,
        custom_elements: 'pagefooter,setpagefooter',
        extended_valid_elements :'setpagefooter[name],setpagefooter[value],pagefooter[name],pagefooter[content-center],pagefooter[content-right],pagefooter[footer-style]',
        height: 600,
        menubar: false,
        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor code',
            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
        ],
        toolbar:
            'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
            alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
            bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help code',

}"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are not using extended_valid_elements correctly.  You don't repeat the tag multiple times in the configuration.  The documentation has working examples:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#extended_valid_elements

For example:

```
extended_valid_elements : 'img[class|src|border=0|alt|title]'
```

...or...

```
extended_valid_elements :'setpagefooter[name|value],pagefooter[name|content-center|content-right|footer-style]',
```

Note that you put all the attributes in one set of brackets.  Here is an example that appears to work for your example content:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/iehaab